# No decryption algorithm for Hummingbird-2?

Tags: block-cipher, stream-cipher

I stumbled upon hummingbird-2 encryption algorithm when I was looking for a lightweight encryption module that can be used in resorce-restrained environments like Network-on-Chips.

A problem I faced when reading https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/126.pdf was that the paper does not mention any decryption procedure and only Initialization, Encryption and computing MAC.

Is the decryption process skipped because it uses the same method as its predecessor (HB1)? Or am I missing something in the paper?

Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, that paper leaves determining the decryption operations to the reader, hinting that "The inverse of f(x) and WD16 can be derived in straightforward fashion". The four S-boxes need to be inverted. The only other mildly difficult to invert part is L. If you are going to implement the algorithm, the whole thing should not be too hard. What have you tried?

Comment: Ohh I was wondering about that sentence too. I suppose I need to figure out how to make the inverse of the given functions. A simple and possibly dumb question (because I'm not familiar to this field), what does the notation of <i> mean in page 3, where t1 = WD16(R1(i) + <i>,K1,K2,K3,K4) ? Is it just adding R1 with the i value?

Comment: Yes, my first guess would be that $\langle i\rangle$ designates the representation of integer $i$ as a big-endian bytestring of the appropriate width for the context, which in $R_1^{(i)}\boxplus\langle i\rangle$ would be 16 bits. So in an implementation $\boxplus\,\langle i\rangle$ would boil down to addition of $i$ modulo $2^{16}$. If you are stuck at inverting a particular part, please [edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/101063/edit) the question to tell which. This could be homework, thus I hesitate to make an answer. And you'll gain knowledge of the algorithm by inverting it !

Comment: Thank you so much!